# Need explanation MPI_Scatter()

Tags: mpi, scatter

Im trying to do the Monte Carlo problem using MPI were we generate x amount of rand. num between 0 and 1 and then send n-length numbers to each processor. I'm using scatter function but my code doesn't run right, it compiles but it doesn't ask for the input. I dont understand how MPI loops by itself without loops, can some explain this and what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int         my_rank;       /* rank of process      */
int         p;             /* number of processes  */
int         source;        /* rank of sender       */
int         dest;          /* rank of receiver     */
int         tag = 0;       /* tag for messages     */
char        message[100];  /* storage for message  */
MPI_Status  status;        /* return status for    */
double *total_xr, *p_xr, total_size_xr, p_size_xr;  /* receive              */

/* Start up MPI */
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

/* Find out process rank  */
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

/* Find out number of processes */
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

double temp;
int i, partial_sum, x, total_sum, ratio_p, area;
total_size_xr = 0;
partial_sum = 0;
if(my_rank == 0){
    while(total_size_xr <= 0){
        printf("How many random numbers should each process get?: ");
        scanf("%f", &p_size_xr);
    }
    total_size_xr = p*p_size_xr;
    total_xr = malloc(total_size_xr*sizeof(double));

    //xr generator will generate numbers between 1 and 0
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<total_size_xr; i++)
    {
        temp = 2.0 * rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0) -1.0;
        //this will make sure if any number computer stays in the boundry of 0 and 1, doesn't go over into the negative
        while(temp < 0.0)
        {
            temp = 2.0 * rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0) -1.0;
        }
        //array set to total random numbers generated to be scatter into processors
        total_xr[i] = temp;
    }

}
else{
//this will be the buffer for the processors to hold their own numbers to add
p_xr = malloc(p_size_xr*sizeof(double));
printf("\n\narray set\n\n");
//scatter xr into processors
MPI_Scatter(total_xr, total_size_xr, MPI_DOUBLE, p_xr, p_size_xr, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//while in processor the partial sum will be caluclated by using xr and the formula sqrt(1-x*x)
for(i=0; i<p_size_xr; i++)
{
    x = p_xr[i];
    temp = sqrt(1 - (x*x));
    partial_sum = partial_sum + temp;
}
//}


//we will send the partial sums to master processor which is processor 0 and add them and place 
//the result in total_sum
MPI_Reduce(&partial_sum, &total_sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

//once we have all of the sums we need to multiply the total sum and multiply it with 1/N
//N being the number of processors, the area should contain the value of pi.
ratio_p = 1/p;
area = total_sum*ratio_p;

printf("\n\nThe area under the curve of f(x) = sqrt(1-x*x), between 0 and 1 is, %f\n\n", area);

/* Shut down MPI */
MPI_Finalize();
} /* main */
```

Comment: some of the variables were not use because i forgot to take them out from my last project please help.

Answer (score 1):

In general, its not good to rely on STDIN/STDOUT for an MPI program. It's possible that MPI implementation could put rank 0 on some node other than the node on which you're launching your jobs. In that case you have to worry about forwarding correctly. While this will work most of the time, it's not usually a good idea.

A better way to do things is to have your user input be in a file that the application can read or via command line variables. Those will be much more portable.

I'm not sure what you mean by MPI looping by itself without loops. Maybe you can clarify that comment if you still need an answer there.